# Powershell creates a square character on copy

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

When copying content to file using PowerShell script square characters are being added:

```
$PSscript = @"
New-PSDrive -Name $driveLetter -Root $drivePath -Persist -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Scope Global
"@
# Add code to the script
Set-Content -Path "$scriptPath\$scriptName" -Value $PSscript -Encoding UTF8
```

[image]

tried with add-content, set-content, >, Out-File - same issue

Comment: Open file with Notepad and see if same issue exists.   To check what encoding Notepad is using go to menu File : SaveAs.  The encoding will be listed in the SaveAs GUI. Often issues like this is not encoding.  The Font that is being used is not compatible with the data.  change Font.

Comment: `out-file -append` or `>>` mixes encodings and wouldn't work.  Add-content should be fine.

Comment: The code you're showing does not explain your symptom.